# When users respond to emails sent from SF how can I prevent ticket getting reassigned?

Tags: email2case

My company recently acquired another company. All the clients at the acquired company still send help requests to support@acquiredcompany.com, so we made it so emails sent to that address will generate tickets and assign them to a queue. We are also having the support team at the acquired company send updates to tickets from that same address. The problem is that when clients respond to these emails it runs the rule again, taking the ticket from whoever took ownership of it and reassigning it to the general queue.

Is there any way to make this rule run only for new tickets, and not for existing tickets? Preferably without having to change the email address that support reps at the acquired company are sending ticket updates from?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's email-to-case feature, on it's own, does not revert a case's owner to the queue. You'll have to dig around to find what is responsible for reverting your cases' owners back to the queue. Here's the first few places I would look:

- Do you have an Email Service responsible for handling inbound emails to support@acquiredcompany.com? If so, determine if the Apex class associated to this Email Service always assigns a case back to a queue.
- Do you have an assignment rule?
- Workflow rule field updates?